# ReSharper Can't Find ASP .NET MVC Views with Dots (.)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resharper-6.0

I'm working with a project that has its partial views named following the convention `SomeName.Widget.ascx`.  Starting with JetBrains ReSharper 6, these can't be resolved; ReSharper thinks they don't exist. For example:

[image]

Any thoughts on how to correct this?  It wasn't an issue with ReSharper 5.

Comment: Are you using a custom view engine? Resharper as great as it is, tends to be poor for MVC stuff, even version 6. If not, send them an email. They're pretty helpful.

Comment: @Finglas: This is MVC 2 using the default view engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this used to work, and nothing has changed, it could be a bug in ReSharper. I would recommend posting in [their forums](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/resharper).

Comment: @Yuck: Not sure if you have this fixed, but I have resharper 6.1 and this is still an issue...

Answer (score 0):

Yuck, this issue is filed http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-274771 and fixed in upcoming 6.1 release.